# Explode datalist into array

Tags: php, explode

I've got a list of data with in the following format:

```
data\n
data\n
data\n
data\n
data\n
```

Now I try to explode it into an array with

```
$array = explode("\n", $dataList);
```

What happens next is that there is a key with no data, I think it is because of the \n on the end.

Is there a way to explode it so that the last key isn't set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you explode, use [array_pop()](http://www.php.net/array_pop) to pop the last item:

```
$array = explode("\n", $dataList);

array_pop($array);
```

You can add an if statement using [count()](http://www.php.net/count) and [empty()](http://www.php.net/empty) if you want to check if the last item contains something other than a linebreak character, but that should get you what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly. You can either:

- Remove the trailing "\n" with `trim`.
- Remove the last element of `$array` with `array_pop`.
- Use `preg_split` instead with the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.

Comment: Yea, I like the trim method, that would probably be better then the array_pop. Nice call there.

Answer (score 2):

Remove empty values by:

$array = array_filter( $array );

Comment: That will also remove entries with "0".